# How can I decide to make photo B&W or leave it color?

Tags: color, black-and-white

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When is black and white likely to enhance an image?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1757/when-is-black-and-white-likely-to-enhance-an-image)

Are there any common photography rules to make black and white photos based on composition or other things?